# opening a terminal with a command on startup in debian

Tags: debian, shell-script, services

I have an application which is an object file (obtained from a c source code).
When I run this application from the terminal it works fine.

I want to run this application on system start up. Since all the log data currently I am printing on the terminal, I want to open the terminal and run this application in terminal (so that I can see the live log and also give input to my application from terminal).

After searching some tutorials I am able to create a service which runs a shell script on startup. I modified this script to open a terminal and run the application.
If I run the shell script only from the terminal it works well.

But when I am running the script from service I am getting following warning:

(x-terminal-emulator:16048): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Where am I making mistake?

Here I am using beaglebone black running with debian.

This is my service code(application.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=application setup

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/application/
ExecStart=/root/application/start_application
SyslogIdentifier=application
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is start_application.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# start_app_server
#

echo "Starting application server"
x-terminal-emulator -e "app_server/a.out"

echo Done
```

Comment: You may want to use "screen".

Answer (score 0):

The *nix way of doing this would be to start the script without a terminal and send the output to a log file. For example:

```
app_server/a.out > /var/log/app_server.log &
```

You can then add it to the user crontab with `@reboot`.

Once that works, the *real* *nix way to do it is to create a service, with some form of [IPC](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/027) if necessary.

Comment: Thank you l0b0 for replying. Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using terminal not only for log but also to give some input to my application. I am working as per your suggestion; here object file runs in background but app_server.log is always empty.

Comment: About logging, you'll want to have a look at [I/O](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput) and [process management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement), and afterwards maybe post a separate question.